# BDH formula not taking an external variable

Tags: python, pdblp

I want to use an external date variable to be used in the bdh formula of the pdblp package. But for some reason .format() is not working in this case.

```
startdate = '20130101' 

df1 = con.bdh(['FV1 Comdty',  'TY1 Comdty'], 'FUT_EQV_DUR_NOTL', '{}', '20190630').format(startdate)
```

It gives me the following error

InvalidArgumentException: Choice sub-element not found for name 'securityData'. (0x00020002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do?

```
df1 = con.bdh(['FV1 Comdty',  'TY1 Comdty'], 'FUT_EQV_DUR_NOTL', startdate, '20190630')
```

Comment: Well that worked. I feel stupid now. I had tried the same thing yesterday but it had not worked. Maybe just carelessness. Anyway thank you for the help

Comment: Happens all the time. Cheers